# Perform UPDATE optimization query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following two `update` statements ->

First:

```
DECLARE @NR NVARCHAR(100);

DECLARE RECORDSORDER CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR


select gid from #CONFIRMEDORDER order by DOCUMENTCODE


OPEN RECORDSORDER
FETCH NEXT FROM RECORDSORDER INTO @NR
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN

 UPDATE MYLINKEDSERVER.SERVER.DBO.DocumentLinesTable
 SET 
 udfvalue1=(SELECT Quantity1 FROM #CONFIRMEDORDER WHERE GID=@NR),
 udfvalue2=(SELECT Quantity2 from #CONFIRMEDORDER WHERE GID=@NR),
 Stringfield1=(SELECT Warehouse FROM #CONFIRMEDORDER WHERE  GID=@NR )
WHERE GID=@NR 

FETCH NEXT FROM RECORDSORDER INTO @NR

END

CLOSE RECORDSORDER DEALLOCATE RECORDSORDER

--the second one comes right after the first one--
```

Second

```
 UPDATE MYLINKEDSERVER.SERVER.DBO.DocumentHeaderTable
 SET 
 DocumentHeaderTable.ADFLAG3=1,
 DocumentHeaderTable.adstringfield3=(SELECT top 1 GRUPCUST FROM #CONFIRMEDORDER)
 WHERE GID IN (SELECT FDOCUMENTGID FROM #CONFIRMEDORDER)
```

LE:
The scenario is the following: I have 5 documents each one with N lines. The first statement goes through the cursor in order to update all the lines in the documents based on some information from a temporary table and the second one, after all the lines are updated in each document, change the document status which is a flag, from 0 to 1.

My problem is: the second statement starts only when all the lines in all the documents are updated (after the first `update` statement), no matter how many they are, and I would like to make it start marking the documents flag with 1 after all the lines in each document are updated. How can I perform this? Thanks

Comment: I'd focus more on that first update statement. You're doing 3 subqueries to update the one table, why not do this as an UPDATE SELECT statement so you only hit #CONFIRMEDORDER once? Also, is that cursor necessary? SQL works better as a set based language. If you could provide some sample data i'm sure that could be done in a more efficient way.

Comment: @RichBenner - please see my LE.

Comment: I need to do 3 subqueries because initially I am sending some information from my DB to another system via XML files and after that, I receive the same information and I need to compare the lines sent versus received.

Comment: You could put your second query into `Begin... end` of cursor, for example `UPDATE MYLINKEDSERVER.SERVER.DBO.DocumentHeaderTable SET...... Where GID = @NR`

Comment: @TriV - I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming Gid is your documentId, the code below should work. However I agree with Rich Benner that you shouldn't use cursors if you don't have to.

```
            DECLARE @NR NVARCHAR(100);
            DECLARE RECORDSORDER CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR

            select gid from #CONFIRMEDORDER order by DOCUMENTCODE

            OPEN RECORDSORDER
            FETCH NEXT FROM RECORDSORDER INTO @NR
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
            BEGIN

            UPDATE MYLINKEDSERVER.SERVER.DBO.DocumentLinesTable
            SET 
            udfvalue1=(SELECT Quantity1 FROM #CONFIRMEDORDER WHERE GID=@NR),
            udfvalue2=(SELECT Quantity2 from #CONFIRMEDORDER WHERE GID=@NR),
            Stringfield1=(SELECT Warehouse FROM #CONFIRMEDORDER WHERE  GID=@NR )
            WHERE GID=@NR 

            UPDATE MYLINKEDSERVER.SERVER.DBO.DocumentHeaderTable
            SET 
            DocumentHeaderTable.ADFLAG3=1,
            DocumentHeaderTable.adstringfield3=(SELECT top 1 GRUPCUST FROM #CONFIRMEDORDER)
            WHERE GID IN @NR

            FETCH NEXT FROM RECORDSORDER INTO @NR

            END

            CLOSE RECORDSORDER DEALLOCATE RECORDSORDER
```

Also try using joins instead of sub queries.

```
            UPDATE dlt
            SET 
                udfvalue1=co.Quantity1,
                udfvalue2=co.Quantity2,
                Stringfield1=co.Warehouse
            from MYLINKEDSERVER.SERVER.DBO.DocumentLinesTable dlt
            join #CONFIRMEDORDER co on dlt.gid = co.gid
            WHERE GID=@NR
```

Comment: And how am I supposed to go through all the records if not using a cursor? Thanks

Comment: You don't need to go through the records, you update them all at once.

Comment: It's not working your query. It marks the documents before all the lines are updated and that is not helping me.